# Comando DELETE em VBA não funciona

Tags: sql, vba, microsoft-access

Tenho um projeto que adiciona e elimina datas, para adicionar tenho o seguinte código:

```
   Set dbs = CurrentDb
   dbs.Execute " INSERT INTO TMP " _
   & "(diaMes) VALUES( " _
    & "'" & tmp7 & "') "
```

onde o tmp7 é a data em dd-mm-yyyy
e funciona perfeitamente

e para retirar uso o seguinte código:

```
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
   dbs.Execute " DELETE * FROM TMP " _
   & "WHERE diaMes=#" & tmp7 & "#;"
```

O problema é que ao eliminar apenas elimina se o dia for superior a 12, ou seja eu entendo que ele, caso o dia seja inferior ou igual a 12 esteja a interpretar como mm-dd-yyyy

o tmp7 é uma string com concatenação de strings.

Como posso forçar a passagem do SQL como dd-mm-yyyy ?

A campo na tabela está assim: 
[image: tabela]

Comment: Valeu amigo, eu tbm tava com esse problema. Obrigado pela ajuda!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Descobri como fazer,

```
    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    dbs.Execute "DELETE * FROM TMP WHERE diaMes = " & _
    Format(tmp7, "\#mm\/dd\/yyyy\#")
```